# Android: Control action to happen if user closes app with Recent Apps Button

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

my app have a availability states to show if user is online or not, now when user closes the app it would gives value of 0 and 1 if he is online.

now when user closes the app with recent apps button there is no activity lifecycle for it so i can't control the action to send info that user is offline.

so any solution to be able to control what happens when user closes app with recent apps?

Comment: `onPause` doesn't work?

Comment: thanks onPuase worked please write it as answer so i can accept it

Comment: Added it as an answer. Glad it works for your use case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update user online status in [`onPause()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPause()).

`onPause()` use-case as per [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPause()).

> This callback is mostly used for saving any persistent state the
> activity is editing, to present a "edit in place" model to the user
> and making sure nothing is lost if there are not enough resources to
> start the new activity without first killing this one. This is also a
> good place to stop things that consume a noticeable amount of CPU in
> order to make the switch to the next activity as fast as possible.